# A question about profit and loss

Tags: problem-solving

A shopkeeper allows a discount of 20% on the marked price but charges 5% sales tax on the marked price and 5% service tax on the discounted price.

If the customer pays Rs. 2670 as price including tax, then what is the marked price on the item?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: 2670+5% of 2670=3204

Comment: Hint: Mark $x=\text{marketed price}$, and then take the percentages into account. You will arrive to an equation from which you will be able to solve $x$.